# creating session via Boto3 is giving error - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'multiprocessing.managers'; 'multiprocessing' is not a package

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to create a simple s3 session in Pycharm and it is not letting me create for the love of God. I have checked multiple times still the same error, can anyone please nudge me in the right direction?

My code -

```
from secrets import AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY, AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, AWS_SESSION_TOKEN
import boto3
import multiprocess as mp
import multiprocessing

session = boto3.session.Session()

session = boto3.session.Session(aws_access_key_id=AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
                                aws_secret_access_key=AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
                                aws_session_token=AWS_SESSION_TOKEN)

s32 = boto3.resource('s3')
```

=============

```
/usr/local/bin/python3.8 /Users/mu/PycharmProjects/Experiments/Get_S3_Files_Add_Partition.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/mu/PycharmProjects/Experiments/Get_S3_Files_Add_Partition.py", line 12, in <module>
    s32 = boto3.resource('s3')
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/boto3/__init__.py", line 100, in resource
    return _get_default_session().resource(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/boto3/session.py", line 384, in resource
    client = self.client(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/boto3/session.py", line 258, in client
    return self._session.create_client(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/session.py", line 835, in create_client
    client = client_creator.create_client(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 80, in create_client
    cls = self._create_client_class(service_name, service_model)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 107, in _create_client_class
    self._event_emitter.emit(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/hooks.py", line 356, in emit
    return self._emitter.emit(aliased_event_name, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/hooks.py", line 228, in emit
    return self._emit(event_name, kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/hooks.py", line 211, in _emit
    response = handler(**kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/boto3/utils.py", line 61, in _handler
    module = import_module(module)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/boto3/utils.py", line 52, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/boto3/s3/inject.py", line 15, in <module>
    from boto3.s3.transfer import create_transfer_manager
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/boto3/s3/transfer.py", line 127, in <module>
    from s3transfer.exceptions import RetriesExceededError as \
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/s3transfer/__init__.py", line 141, in <module>
    import s3transfer.compat
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/s3transfer/compat.py", line 173, in <module>
    from multiprocessing.managers import BaseManager
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'multiprocessing.managers'; 'multiprocessing' is not a package
```

Comment: You have a file called `multiprocessing.py` that's shadowing the multiprocessing package itself.  Remove or rename this file so it doesn't conflict.

Comment: Thanks a lot Anon! it works now!! this was very stupid! Thanks again @anon-coward

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the [AWS SDK Github](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples) where code examples are located. Your code looks different from the Python examples. See this example.

https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/main/python/example_code/s3/s3_basics/demo_bucket_basics.py

Comment: hey @smac2020 , thanks for sharing this, stupidly I had a multiprocessing.py file in my working directory and hence the issue. Thanks again for your help..